# return an array of object's names sorted by the object's age from youngest to oldest

Tags: javascript

im given an array of objects. The objects contain the properties name  and age . i have to return an array of object's names sorted by the object's age from youngest to oldest.

```
sortArray([{name:'bob', age:96}, {name:'tom', age:24}, {name:'tim', age:65}])
```

should just return ['tom', 'tim', 'bob']

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `arr.sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age).map((e) => e.name)`

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort that array and then use the function `map` to extract the sorted names.

*This approach doesn't mutate the original array.*

```js
let sortArray = (arr) => arr.slice().sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age).map(({name}) => name);
console.log(sortArray([{name:'bob', age:96}, {name:'tom', age:24}, {name:'tim', age:65}]));
```